# Script - Lenovo Battery Recall

Tags: script, batch-file, battery

**Problem:**
LenovoBattery.exe fails when called via batch file. Is there a way to make it work?

**Details:**
Lenovo has expanded its voluntary recall of notebook batteries.
They request the industry to run their utility, *LenovoBattery.exe*, and submit the generated .csv to their respective Lenovo Sales Rep.

Their documentation states the example is not compatible with .bat files.

**Scope:**
SCCM 2012 R2 CU4
Lenovo Laptops

> Info:
> http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/documents/hf004122
> http://www.lenovo.com/batteryprogram2014
>
> Download Utility:
> http://www.lenovoengineering.com/batteryprogram2014/batteryutility.zip
>
> Manual Serial Check:
> https://lenovobattery2014.orderz.com/

Comment: There's no question here. I understand you're trying to help, but this feels super spammy.

Comment: I appreciate your feedback! If you would gladly hold a simple token of your inheritance in your bank account, you will be greatly rewarded! Please reply with your bank info... :D  </sarcasm>

This post was originated as a KB. There is little info regarding this topic that I was able to locate on the net, and this is my chosen venue for contribution. If a mod wants this to be Jeopardy, the post can be edited to pose a question. I am happy to do it myself also.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to deploy a package containing the following batch file and lenovo's utility:

> - CheckBattery.bat
> - LenovoBattery.exe

CheckBattery.bat - -
This .bat will check to make sure it can communicate with the file share, then will execute, saving the .csv.   If the share is unreachable the script will exit.

```
:Check Network
Ping server.domain
if %errorlevel%==1 GOTO Offline
if %errorlevel%==0 GOTO Online

:Offline
echo Offline
EXIT 4

:Online
echo Online
SET @VAR="--output-to-file \\server.domain\_Scripts\LenovoBatteryCheck\Results --cname"
"%~dp0LenovoBattery.exe" /verysilent /CMD=%@VAR%
exit 0
```

The resulting CSVs can be zipped and delivered to one's Lenovo handler, who will report back with the results of which individual batteries are in need of recall.

Hope this helps.